# RPM is not working with i386 (rhel6) but it works with x86_64(rhel5)

Tags: x86-64, rpm, rhel, i386

While installing the package `Test-5.0-201208280707.amd64.rpm`

I have a 64 bit RHEL 6 Machine and it's architecture is i386 :

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)
# rpm --eval '%{_arch}'
i386
```

When I try to install a package using `rpm` :

```
rpm -ihv Test-5.0-201208280707.amd64.rpm
```

it complain me the error :

```
package Test-5.0-201208280707.amd64 is intended for a amd64 architecture
```

When the same thing I try with x86_64 rhel5 architecture it work fine

Answer (score 1):

Your 64-bit machine is running in 32 bit mode.

In 32 bit mode, you can only install 32 bit rpm's.

In 64 bit mode, you can install both 32 bit and 64 bit rpm's.

If you really want to install 64 bit mode rpm's like the on you have, you will have to reinstall your system with a 64 bit install disc instead.

Answer (score 0):

> **package Test-5.0-201208280707.amd64 is intended for a amd64 architecture**

RPM is precompiled pack, and the installer is supposed for an architecture of type x86_64 and not i386. You cant install executables on different platform rather than one, which it is meant for.Otherwise result may be devastating.

Comment: It is built for x86_64 thats why

Comment: @anish:- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/i386-vs-x86_64-a-413527/